# GLUT can't set display callback in gamemode

Tags: c, opengl, mingw, glut

I'm using Glut with C, and I compile my code with MinGW GCC 4.7.2 with the GLUTMing implementation of GLUT.
My main entry-point looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {


// init GLUT and create window
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
glutInitWindowSize(800,600);
glutCreateWindow("GLW");
glClearColor(0.2,0.2,1.0,1.0);
// enter gamemode
glutGameModeString("800x600:32");
if (glutGameModeGet(GLUT_GAME_MODE_POSSIBLE))
    glutEnterGameMode();
else {
    printf("The select mode is not available\n");
    exit(1);
}
// register callbacks
glutDisplayFunc(renderScene);
glutIdleFunc(renderScene);

// OpenGL init
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

glutMainLoop();

return 0;
}
```

And the render callback function i point to looks like this:

```
void renderScene(void) {
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glColor3f(0.9f, 0.9f, 0.9f);
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glVertex3f(-2,-2,-5.0);
    glVertex3f(0,2,-5.0);
    glVertex3f(2,-2,-5.0);
glEnd();
glutSwapBuffers();
glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

My program runs fine in windowed mode, but adding `glutEnterGameMode();` crashes my program at start and returns the error: `redisplay needed for window 1, but no display callback.`

I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong here.
As far as I'm aware, I'm entering the `glutMainLoop();` in the proper order with a call to `glutPostRedisplay();`.

Is there something I'm missing when entering gamemode?

Comment: Which GLUT implementation are you using?  Also, edit in a [mcve].

Comment: I'm using GLUTMing:
http://chortle.ccsu.edu/Bloodshed/glutming.zip

Comment: Does calling `glutEnterGameMode()` after `glutDisplayFunc(renderScene);` solve the problem?

Comment: @BDL I've tried this both ways, and calling it after displayFunc ony results in a black screen.

Comment: @Boyfinn sounds like it's supposed to be after displayFunc then, but it's not rendering right. I bet entering game mode resets OpenGL. Did you try setting the clear colour, etc, after entering game mode?

Comment: @Boyfinn: Fine, but that's then a new problem to solve. You can't enter Gamemode before setting the callback. Also note, that large parts of your triangle are outside the visible area, and that you might need to adjust the viewport since the resolution might change when entering game mode.

Comment: After a second look, I'm actually quite surprised that the code displays anything in window mode. The triangle is at z=-5, but the default visible range is [-1, 1]. Unless there is more code involved than you show, you should only see an empty screen.

Comment: @BDL No, I definitely have a white triangle in the middle of my screen. The background color renders now that i set the clear color after entering gamemode. Though the triangle is no longer visible when I'm in this mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out creating a window in the first place using `glutCreateWindow();` prevents OpenGL from entering gamemode. I skipped everything after first initializing glut and went straight to calling `glutEnterGameMode();` and this works fine.